# How would I convert a character vector into a message? C# R.NET

Tags: c#, r, r.net

Here is my current code:

```
private string result;
        private string result1;

        public async Task calCasync(string ar)
        {
            REngine engine;
            REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
            engine = REngine.GetInstance();
            engine.Initialize();
            CharacterVector vector = engine.Evaluate(ar).AsCharacter();
            result = vector[0];

            ReplyAsync("> " + result);
            try
            {
                result1 = String.Join(" ", vector.Cast<int>());
                ReplyAsync("> ");
                ReplyAsync("ad> " + result1);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }`
```

I have tried to modify some parts of it to make it work, but it only responds with 'result' and not 'result1'. In this I would like to convert a matrix or a vector into a string which I can use for further things.

```
result = vector[1];
```

or higher gives a error saying that it is too high. Every time executed `result1 = String.Join(" ", vector.Cast<int>());` gives a error. I have not found any information online on this topic. If it does help I am using visual studio 2017.

Thanks
-Yan

Comment: Okay, it's a discussion ... how does this relate to the R programming language?

Comment: This is a api that lets you run R commands in c#

Comment: Okay, likely I misread it ... are your problems with the R side of things, or with the C# of things.

Comment: I honestly dont know, probably both.

Comment: While I think this reads like it is solely on the C# side of things, I can see some utility in keeping the R tags involved. I'll purge my previous comments, thanks. (I don't see math/stats, though ... if I misread that, too, feel free to add them back in.) Sorry about that.

Comment: What value are you passing for `ar`?

Comment: I am parsing the equation provided by the user such as (1+1 or cbind(1,1,2,2,3)) ETC.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was by using

```
CharacterVector vector1 = engine.Evaluate(ar).AsCharacter();
    string[] resp1 = engine.Evaluate(ar).AsCharacter().ToArray();
```

then using

```
result1 = ConvertStringArrayToString(resp1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it into a string with a loop.  The indices start at i=0.  so you only go up to the (Length-1), thus the condition i<Length.

```
        //evalutate R code
        CharacterVector vector = engine.Evaluate(_r_code).AsCharacter();
        //string to hold r result
        string result="";
        for (int i=0; i<vector.Length; i++){
            if (i==0){
                result=vector[i];
            }else{
                result=result+" "+vector[i];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my Code.

Open the R Editor and type the below code:

```
characters <- c("H","E","L","L","O")
stringdata <- paste(characters,collapse="")
```

Type characters in R console window Then

Output : "H" "E" "L" "L" "O"

Type stringdata in R console window Then

Output : "HELLO"

for paste function in R refer the below documentation

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/paste